# Modify SeaGlass JComponents

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I'm trying to create a variant of JTextField to make it look more like a 'search' field, I've seen this on the SeaGlass website but am having trouble implementing it... The look and feel itself work perfectly, but I cannot access the JTextField.variant method... I'm testing it a the following class:

```
public class Stuff extends JFrame {

    JTextArea text;
    JTextField field;

    public Stuff() {
        text = new JTextArea("something");
        text.setEditable(false);
        field = new JTextField(20).variant("search");            
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());            
        add(text);
        add(field);            
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 300);
    }
}
```

and calling it in this class:

```
public class SeaGlassTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
            new Stuff();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it! For future reference, the code you need is:

```
field.putClientProperty("JTextField.variant", "search");
```